# Mount encfs volume via RDP client

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, mount, encfs

On a Windows machine with *Windows 7* installed I created an *encfs volume* in Dropbox using *encfs4win*. I can mount this volume without a problem when I am working on that machine.

I tried to mount that encfs volume over an RDP connection but that doesn't work. I can choose the key icon in the status bar pint to the right folder and enter the passphrase but the mounted DOKAN drive won't show. When I enter the wrong passphrase I will get a warning.

I tried *Rdesktop* on Linux and *CoRD* on OS X. I don't have another native windows machine at hand to try that with the real Windows RDP client.

**Why is it not possible to mount an encfs volume via RDP or how do I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to my problem:
Open encfsw.exe as Administrator and you'll be able to mount encfs folders over RDP.